# How to know if this book (The Hero With A Thousand Face) is free of rights?

Tags: copyright

I want to translate and publish this ebook: The Hero With A Thousand Face into my native language (French) and am wondering if this is free of rights. The first edition was published in 1949 which is more than 70 years ago and make it free of right theoretically. However there was a second edition published in 1968? Does that impact the copyright? How to know if The Hero With A Thousand Face is free of rights?

Comment: This answer may be instructive: https://law.stackexchange.com/a/16987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @rgchris pointed out, copyright laws in Europe state that an opus goes in the public domain 70 years after the death of its author... and Campbell died in 1987. I think you should contact the Campbell Foundation.